# PC randomly freezes with weird patterns / artifacts on screen

Tags: cpu

I just got a new PC (which I assembled myself) having a Core i5 4670K and a Gigabyte Z97MX-Gaming 5 motherboard. I use the Intel HD graphic 4600 as the GPU. I am experiencing weird PC freezes which occur randomly (nothing to do with CPU/GPU load) where the system gets stuck and the screen shows weird patterns/rectangular artifacts which constantly move.
I already installed the latest Intel HD graphics drivers and I got the latest BIOS firmware.
Also checked the CPU and system temperature and nothing seems wrong.

Has anyone experienced this behavior?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you perform any form of overclocking? Also, make sure you keep the boxes in hand. You may have a component that has a problem (it happens) and you may need to send it back to the computer store to get a replacement part. Just make sure its not a screwup in assembly.

Comment: I didn't perform any overclocking, all clocks and voltages are set to factory values. I also performed a memory check - which turned out OK, and did a CPU, and GPU stress tests, both came out fine. this problem comes at total random times.

Comment: Then doggyTourettes solution seems the best approach. Try reseating stuff, and otherwise contact the  manufacturer for RMA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With updated BIOS and drivers these kind of problems are often solved by reseating components such as memory and graphics cards. You can try reseating the memory easy enough, but the Intel chip is on-board is it not?

Reseat what you can, with care. If it doesn't resolve the problem I'd be straight back to the supplier with it.

Comment: Thanks. I reseated the memory DIMM and the CPU, and reconnected all internal connectors this morning. will update whether the problem is solved or not.

Comment: So I gave the rig 48 hours after reseating the componenets, I also changed the RAM slot of the single memory DIMM I have, and everything worked fine with no crashes. This morning I moved the memory DIMM back to its original slot just to make sure everything still works and the crashes came right back :(
I'm currently running Memtest86 (while the memory DIMM is still in the "problematic" slot) and so far it doesn't show any errors.
Do you think this could actually be a problem with one of the RAM slots? and if so - how can I prove this to be true (to the MB supplier as well)?

Comment: The Memory Support List can be downloaded [from this page](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4968#dl). Check your memory make/type is on this list. Might be worth a quick email to Gigabyte tech if it isn't.

Comment: The manual for the board can be downloaded via the drop-down comboboxes at the top of the same page. Once upon a time a single stick of RAM would need to be assigned to the first slot, (DIMM0 or DIMM1 depending on the numbering), but the manual does state this as a requirement on your board. It does mention that dual channel memory mode 'cannot' be enabled unless either 2 or 4 DIMMs are present. Have you checked these settings in your BIOS?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! The memory chip I have is G.Skill F3-1600C11S-8GNT, it is stated as supported in the "Supported Memory List" in the MB webpage. I'll look for settings regarding dual channel in the BIOS.

Comment: EDIT OF LAST COMMENT: Once upon a time a single stick of RAM would need to be assigned to the first slot, ..., but the manual does ***NOT*** state this as a requirement on your board.

Comment: Turns out to be a problem with the memory stick, even though every test possible found no error with it. anyway, I changed it to another one (same model and everything) and all is OK now. Thanks for the help!!